# Script using command prompt to check if a folder is not empty, then create sub-folders

Tags: cmd.exe, script

I'm trying to generate 3 folders for each sub-folder of a parent folder.
I only need to generate the 3 folders if the sub-folder is empty.

I have a script that works great but I'm struggling with checking for nul:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:d`) do (
rem enter the directory
pushd %%a
echo In Directory: %%a
#stuck here. if folder is empty { 
md "Folder 1"
md "Folder 2"
md "Folder 3"
#}
rem leave the directory
popd
)
endlocal
```

Comment: [Is a folder empty? | Windows batch file - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-empty.html)

Comment: You could also simply do the md commands no matter what (assuming that you want these no matter what) and eat the error (as in send it to NUL).

Comment: @DavidPostill. I saw that but unsure what I need to modify. Is the "%_folder%" missing in my case or should I remove the "/a:d" and make it "a". I can't find a more detailed explanation online.

Or should I add the md commands after the loop? In which case it wouldn't loop. Sounds like I need the reverse of that command or a NOT to reverse it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I'd like to avoid creating those folders if there's anything at all in the subfolder. The new folders are only needed if the folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bath
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

2>nul cd /d "C:\Full\Path\To\Root\Target\Foder" || exit /b
set "_cnt=0" && set "_dir=md "Folder 1" "Folder 2" "Folder 3""

for /r "%cd%" /d %%i in (*)do %__AppDir__%tree.exe /a "%%~dpnxi" | find "\-" 1>nul || 2>nul =;(
     1>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe "%%~dpnxi:*.*" || =;( set /a "_cnt+=1"
         call set "_!_cnt!=%%~fi" && echo\In Directory: "%%~fi"
        );=
    );=

for /L %%L in (1,1,!_cnt!)do cd /d "!_%%~L!" && call !_dir! && =;(
     dir /a:d /b /s "!_%%~L!" | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /e "Folder.1 Folder.2 Folder.3"
    );=
    
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 5 & endlocal
```